# How can I implement smooth digging effects in a tile-based game?

Tags: physics, phaser

I'm trying to make a [Dig Dug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_Dug) styled game where you will be digging into a material. This is going to be a tile-based HTML5 game and I have decided to use the Phaser framework.

One way to do the digging mechanic is to break the play area into tiles and remove tiles as the player sprite collides. But I would like to have a smooth digging animation/physics, so it appears that the player character "carves" out the soil as it digs through. Any tips on how I should do this? Right now I have 15x15px tiles while the player is 45x45px, this sort-of fakes the smooth digging I want. Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you simply want the soil to disappear not the entire tile at once but like the "eraser"-tool of Gimp. In that case you could if the movement is tile-based try to achive what you want with an animated texture that you rotate depending on the position of the player relative to the tile that is being removed. But I'm not quite sure if that is what you are looking for? Maybe you could add some extra Information on what it is you actually want to achive.

Comment: Yes you are right, I want it to be like the eraser tool of Gimp or any image editor. What I'm doing now is that I'm making the tiles smaller than the character so it kind of appears that the soil is being carved out..

Comment: Do you want the animation to be smoother, or does your data model have to change too? How are your animation/physics structured at the moment? This needs more detail of what you want to do and what you've tried.

Comment: Right now I have a tiles that are 15x15 px while the character is 45x45 px. I'm deleting the tiles as the character overlaps with them. I'm using the Phaser engine. This kind of fakes the smooth digging animation/physics that I want. The idea is to dig tunnels and then the AI will spawn in the dug area and chase the player. I feel that I should stick to tiles to keep the AI easier..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is reasonable. A simpler alternative would be to use canned sprite states for each tile, representing various levels of "dug out"-ness of the tile (100% full, 80% full, 50% full, all the way to an empty tile). But it sounds like you want something more dynamic, so you're on the right track.

When you implement this kind of technique it's important to note that you do not need to store the *entire world* at the small (15x15) tile resolution. You can store the world as the larger (45x45) tile size (or, indeed, larger if you wish. This means you have few tiles to track in-memory, particularly for dealing with the AI pathfinding, which can be optimal.

When your player hits a tile, you break the tile down into smaller pieces then and there, and being removing them as the player continues to collide with them. This hierarchical approach will help in terms of the number of individual sprites and objects you need to track (as well as with the pathfinding as detailed above).

In fact you can leverage this to further optimize pathfinding by only having the AI consider a 45x45 tile passable if some certain percentage of it's smaller 15x15 tiles (say 75%) have been removed.

In general the hierarchical approach will probably scale better -- you can use an even smaller "digging" resolution of maybe 5x5, or several layers of hierarchy if you want, and you won't suffer the performance impact of keeping your *entire map* at 5x5 resolution. Only the parts where the player has dug the map out.

Comment: For scaling, depending on the number of different tile types, you could potentially store both the tile type and the tile state (which sub-tiles have been removed) in a single 16-32 bit value (e.g. via using Int16Array in Javascript to store the map).

Comment: To expand a little, I believe the pattern of certain areas breaking down to smaller parts is pretty much a *quadtree* style pattern.